# error install my package python using pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have some problem in installing the package in python.

I made a python package itself like this

```
def joke():
    return ('test')
```

and save it with the name `__init__.py`
then I upload to pypi and I have the massage that:

```
Submitting dist/funni3st-0.2.tar.gz to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

then I tried to install the package using pip

```
sudo pip install funni3st

Collecting funni3st
  Downloading funni3st-0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: funni3st
  Running setup.py install for funni3st ... done
Successfully installed funni3st-0.2
```

I tried to run this package in spyder python, I have the massage

```
import funni3st
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named funni3st
```

anyone can help me what's wrong with my python module?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are running and installed the package into Python2 and not Python3, or vice-versa?

Comment: I'm sure its python 2.7, my computer doesn't installed python 3

Comment: Might be recommended to write / learn Python3 if you are just starting. There's doesn't seem to be a reason to limit your module to Python2

Comment: try 'pip freeze' command to list all the installed packages - check if funni3est is there.

Answer (score 2):

import funniest

This should work. It seems that packaged with a wrong name.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ pip2 install funni3st
Requirement already satisfied: funni3st in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Looks like you named it `funniest`

```
$ cat /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/funniest/__init__.py

def joke():
    return (u'Wenn ist das Nunst\u00fcck git und Slotermeyer? Ja! ... '
            u'Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput.')
```

And works fine, by the way

```
In [1]: import funniest

In [2]: funniest.joke()
Out[2]: u'Wenn ist das Nunst\xfcck git und Slotermeyer? Ja! ... Beiherhund das Oder die Flipperwaldt gersput.'
```